# Suppose $FrA= \emptyset$ then there is an x in cl(A) but not in A, why?

Tags: general-topology

So I was studying topology and I came across this in some notes of the Munkres' Topology, if the frontier of a set is empty and A is not a closed set, then there must exist an x in the closure but not in the set, why is that?

Comment: If $A$ is not a closed set, then $\overline A\supsetneq A$, and therefore there is some $x\in\overline A\setminus A$.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now.

Comment: "if the frontier of a set [A] is empty and A is not a closed set" -- this is contradictory.  If the frontier of a set is empty, the set is both open and closed.

Comment: @BrianMoehring yeah, the notes take this to set a contradiction, but I wasn't clear on how if A is only open there is an element in clA but not in A. But José Carlos helped.